# VBA IF condition

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Please help,  I am new and I'm trying to do an If condition.  Here is my code but I need -

```
UnitUsed.Value = If Description.Value=Cells(1,7).Value = "Ton" Then Acres.Value=Cells(1,5).Value * Rate.Value=Cells(1,6).Value/2000 Else Acres.Value=Cells(1,5).Value * Rate.Value=Cells(1,6)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in writing the If condition.

```
Private Sub PopulateForm(SelectedRow As Range)

        With SelectedRow
    
        Calendar1.Value = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        CropFieldName.Value = .Cells(1, 2).Value
        CropType.Value = .Cells(1, 3).Value
        Description.Value = .Cells(1, 7).Value
        Product.Value = .Cells(1, 4).Value
        Acres.Value = .Cells(1, 5).Value
        Rate.Value = .Cells(1, 6).Value
        Price.Value = .Cells(1, 9).Value
        UnitUsed.Value = .Cells(1, 8).Value
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your `IF` code here. Can you explain in english instead of psuedocode? It looks like you are trying to set both `UnitUsed.Value` AND `Acres.Value` with this which doesn't make sense. (I deleted my answer, if you saw it, as it wasn't likely to solve your issue).

Comment: @JNevill If the description value = "Ton" then take Acres value * Rate value /2000 otherwise take Acres value * Rate value.   I need the outcome to populate in UnitUsed

Comment: =IFERROR(IF([@Unit]="Ton",[@Acres]*[@Rate]/2000,[@Acres]*[@Rate]),"") If I put this in my spreadsheet - when I add a new entry - it gives me an inconsistent calculated formula error - in which i can restore but I'm trying to just add it as VBA to prevent this issue.  Unit = Description in the vba code

Answer (score 2):

What do you need would be something like this?

In several lines:

```
If description.Value = "Ton" Then
    Acres.Value = Acres.Value * Rate.Value / 2000
Else
    Acres.Value = Acres.Value * Rate.Value
End If
```

In one line:

```
Acres.Value = IIF(description.Value = "Ton", Acres.Value * Rate.Value / 2000, Acres.Value * Rate.Value)
```

Comment: thank you - I edited from Acres.Value to UnitUsed.Value and it works for the calculation.  However, on the spreadsheet it does not populate the UnitUsed.Value unless I go back to the record and click "update"

Comment: UnitUsed.Value depends on what do you have in Cells(1, 8).Value , after executing your PopulateForm method. But if the IF/IIF issue is already solved, i would recommend you to isolate the new problem and ask it in a new thread, giving all the needed information.